# Is there a point to this line of code?

Tags: java, user-interface

I was having a hard time making a sudoku grid using textfields until i came across someones code on dreamincode, but they didnt really explain and i was wondering if anyone here could explain the cells class to me. ive been wondering about this because even if the class is empty the grid still works so im confused. thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;


public class Squares extends JPanel {

    public final int CELL_COUNT = 9;
    public Cell [] cells = new Cell[CELL_COUNT];

    public Squares(){
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK,2));
        for(int i = 0; i<CELL_COUNT; i++){
            cells[i] = new Cell();
            this.add(cells[i]);
        }
    }

    public class Cell extends JTextField{

        private int number;
        public Cell(){

        }
         public void setNumber(int number){
             this.number = number;
             this.setText("1");
         }
        public int getNumber(){

            return number;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Asking to explain that code?

Comment: pretty much, like i said i found it but the author didnt explain it and i found it curios that i could remove everything from the Cells class and it would still work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no Java Pro, but I'll try to explain it best I can.

```
public class Squares extends JPanel
```

The class `Squares` extends `JPanel`, which means that it is a child of the `JPanel` class and will behave as one. So, like you add stuff into a `JPanel`, you can add stuff (labels, textfields, etc.) directly into the `Squares` class.

```
public class Cell extends JTextField
```

Similarly, the class `Cell` extends `JTextField`, which means that the objects of this class behave like a textfield. `setText()` can be used upon them and they can be added to a `JPanel`.

Here is the constructor of the `Squares` class

```
public Squares(){
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK,2));
    for(int i = 0; i<CELL_COUNT; i++){
        cells[i] = new Cell();
        this.add(cells[i]);
    }
}
```

In this constructor, firstly the layout and border have been set. Then a loop is run which instanciates new objects of `Cell` class (which are basically `JTextField`s). And these cells are added to the `Squares` (child of `JPanel`) class.

Hope you understood it!

---

#### Edit :

In a comment, you said that even when you remove everything from the `Cell` class, it still works. That's because the class extends `JTextField` and it gets all the properties of its parent class. Just simply try removing the `extends JTextField`. It will not work then.

Answer (score 0):

Cells a inner class which extends JTextField. All what it really does is sets/gets a number and displays it.

this may be confusing :

```
public Cell [] cells = new Cell[CELL_COUNT];
```

What he is doing here is creating a array of type Cells. Like you have array of integers, or strings, this one has a type Cell.

Here, he initializing each element of the array cells:

```
cells[i] = new Cell();
```

and this adds it to the grid (notice it extends jpanel):

```
this.add(cells[i]);
```